# How ApolloGraphQL related to GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I need to do a research on GraphQL and this confused me.

As I understand, ApolloGraphQL is some kind of framework/service that based on top of GraphQL (just like ExpressJS compared to Nodejs, Laravel framework compared to PHP)

Is that correct?

Thank you very much

Comment: Apollo Client is the ultra-flexible, community driven GraphQL client for React, JavaScript, and native platforms. It is designed from the ground up to make it easy to build UI components that fetch data with GraphQL... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GraphQL is a different way to interact with data. Under the hoods, it works through a single API endpoint - typically /graphql. And there is a client tool graphiql to make queries and perform mutations.

Apollo is a framework to implement GraphQL both on the client and the server. Most developers I know use Express-GraphQL to implement the server part as it is the recommended way. And they use Apollo client to connect to the Express-GraphQL server component.

Stephen Grider has a wonderful course in Udemy which teaches GraphQL and Apollo client. And he uses Express-GraphQL over the Apollo server to implement GraphQL on the server.

Answer (score 2):

**GraphQL** is **a language** that is mostly used right now as an `API` on top of your Node.js server (so server-side)

**Apollo** is a **client-side library** that is made to **consume GraphQL APIs**

So, for a popular setup (express + GraphQL + Apollo),

- express and GraphQL will execute server-side
- The GraphQL API will be exposed a `/graphql`
- Apollo will be executed client-side (in the browser for example) and will consume the API at `/graphql`

Comment: Thank you @whitep4nther. But I checked here https://www.apollographql.com/servers, Apollo is not only a client, it's what makes me confused

Comment: apollographql.com/servers is a suite of tool to help expose your GraphQL endpoint, nothing more  
It's not a server, they called it that way probably because it's executed server-side but it's confusing I agree

Answer (score 0):

> Yes you are correct on that point

ApolloGraphQL is framework for graphql like express framework for rest apis.
You can implement graphql without AppoloServer , but Appolo gives you easy ways to apply graphql that's why we use framework.